# How do I remove the slash that appeared right after the body tag?

Tags: codeigniter

My website was working fine, when all of a sudden a slash appeared right after the body tag. I tried to find out what was wrong but I had no luck.
How to fix this?
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
          <title>Toucan | <?=$title?></title>
          <?php $this->load->view('include/head'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="container">
              <?php $this->load->view('include/header'); ?>
              <?= $slideshow ?>
              <table id="main">
                 <tr>
                    <?php if ($sidebar):?>
                        <td width="150px"><div id="sidebar"><?= $sidebar ?></div></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <td><div id="content"><?= $content ?></div></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
              <?php $this->load->view('include/footer'); ?>
           </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you just pasted the image?
Can you share the Source Code of this file too.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the end of your controller to check if you have a PHP closing tag : `?>`. And maybe something like `/` after it...

This is good practice to [omit the PHP closing tag](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html#php_closing_tag) at the end of your scripts.

Comment: You're right, I had the slash in my controller, and have no idea at all how it got there :D Thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't matter how it got there, you should omit the PHP closing tag in you controllers and models.

Comment: actually I never insert a closing tag, I think it helps escape the white spaces making the loading faster

Answer (score 0):

I just google your webpage (toucan-eng.com) and a slash is showing in the main webpage. The `title` tag should be inside the `head` tag and then you need to put the `body` tag. Hope this can help you

[image: Toucan webpage]

Comment: I just pasted my code in the question. In the code, I did what u said, but when I view the site's code, it looks wrong.

Comment: You can use this tool to parse your html and see if a tag or a `/` is missing. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I already ran it and there are a lot of tags that are not closed. Hope this can help you :)